# Share User Object between App and App Extension in iOS8

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-app-extension, pocket

I am using [Pocket API](https://github.com/Pocket/Pocket-ObjC-SDK) and authenticating the user on the app.

While in the extension i want to use the logged in user to run methods to call various endpoints. The only option to share data between the app and its extension is NSUserDefaults as I see on various threads but NSUserDefaults cannot save NSObjects of logged in user.

How can I use the logged in user in the Extention ?

I am logging the user like this in the app..

```
[[PocketAPI sharedAPI] loginWithHandler: ^(PocketAPI *API, NSError     *error){
    if (error != nil)
    {   
            NSlog (@"User Logged In"); 
    }
}];
}
```

and in the extension i want to use :

```
[[PocketAPI sharedAPI] saveURL:url handler: ^(PocketAPI *API, NSURL *URL,
                                              NSError *error){
    if(error){
        NSLog(@"There was an error in saving the URL : %@ ", [error description]);


    }else{
        NSLog(@"URL was saved successfully ");

    }
}];
```

how do i dynamically save the [PocketAPI sharedAPI] to use any method on either side?
How can i share the same instance of the object

Answer (score 0):

For saving user credentials better store in Keychain, it is more secure and you can access in extension also.

1. You can share keychain using **kSecAttrAccessGroup** [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/FileProvider.html) 
   will explain it.
2. Other option would be to share the core data or sqlite file in the shared container. I have done sample explanation in [My Blog on Document Provider](https://pavansaberjack.wordpress.com/) which will explain the sharing of data between app and the extension.